# Update values from CheckBox with angular in sharepoint

Tags: angular, sharepoint

**Here When i checked the checkbox only then the checked checkbox value is updated with the previous values otherwise it doesn't update with the previous value. it just added nothing though there were checked chekboxes. I'm working on SharePoint and using rest API.**
This is my html

```
<div class="form-group" ng-repeat = "option in beftnBranchChecker track by $index">
    <div class="checkerMakerLabel">
         <label><input type="checkbox" ng-value="option" ng-checked="{{resultForBEFTNBranchChecker[$index]}}" ng-model="UpdateBEFTNBranchChecker[option]">{{option}}</label>
    </div>
```

this is my controller code

```
var UpdateBEFTNBranchCheck = [];
angular.forEach($scope.UpdateBEFTNBranchChecker, function (selected,option) {
        if(selected){ 
           UpdateBEFTNBranchCheck.push(option);
          }
                 });
newUserAccessSvc.updateUserBeftn(UpdateBEFTNBranchCheck)
                   .then(function () {                     
                           newUserAccessSvc.closeLoading();
                           alert("User BEFTN Update request has been submitted successfully.");                                                                          
                   }, function (error) {
                       newUserAccessSvc.closeLoading();
                       alert("Error occurred in User BEFTN.");
                   });
```

this is my service code

```
function updateUserBeftn(beftnBranchCheck) {        
        var data = {
            "__metadata": {
                "type": "SP.Data.UsersBEFTNListItem"
            },
            "BranchCheckerInward" : {
                "results" : beftnBranchCheck
            }
        };        
        var url = "/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Users BEFTN')/GetItemById(" + userBEFTN.id + ")";
        return spBaseService.updateRequest(data, url);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<div class="form-group" ng-repeat = "option in beftnBranchChecker track by $index">
    <div class="checkerMakerLabel">
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox" 
          ng-value="option.Value" 
          ng-checked="option.IsbeftnBranchChecked" 
          ng-model="option.IsbeftnBranchSelected">{{option}}
        </label>
</div>
```